# I'm building an Android app for one person and only that person should access it. How do I keep it secure?

Tags: account-security

Assuming that person may leak the APK to another person with security expertise (and even tell the password), how do I ensure the app is made (practically) inaccessible to anyone but that person?

Comment: Not through technical means. Maybe try legal ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use multiple checks on the device itself to verify that the apk has not been shared (IMEI, android id, phone number, etc). This will likely only serve to slow the other person "with security expertise" from gaining access. Given the right level of knowledge, skill, time and determination, a clever individual can spoof all of these identifying properties.

It all depends on how badly you care that someone else may get their hands on it.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of device IMEI. Thanks!

Comment: is device IMEI really a good idea? The app then only works for one **device**, while your question was how to make it accessible for one **person**.

Comment: More importantly, the person obtaining the apk can just change the source code and remove all the checks or replace the values. Reversing an apk and changing it is relatively easy. I really don't think that securing the app only on the client side is possible if the respective checks are not enforced server-side as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit entry by adding in a login page with Google Or Facebook Oauth. And only allow entry with certain email addresses.